Can the gallium anomaly be explained by the transformation of neutrinos to electrons?
A 2024 review of the gallium anomaly summarizes the issue as follows:

The measurements of the charged-current capture rate of neutrinos on 71-Ga from strong radioactive sources have yielded results below those expected, based on the known strength of the principal transition supplemented by theory. The mystery of this anomaly, which has persisted for over two decades, deepened with recent, high-precision results from the Baksan Experiment on Sterile Transitions (BEST).

The scale of  the anomaly is about 20% less germanium atoms produced than predicted.
Can this anomaly be explained by the interaction of gallium atoms with neutrinos as being due to the transformation of energetic neutrinos to electrons and not as lately proposed due to dark matter sterile neutrinos?
The sterile neutrinos (i.e. dark matter candidate) explains this anomaly by suggesting that some of the time the neutrinos oscillate to sterile neutrinos that do not interact with the gallium atoms and therefore this about 20% deficiency in production of germanium atoms is observed. This would be an indirect experiment confirmation of the existence of possible massive right-chirality sterile neutrinos which are a candidate for dark matter.
What is asked here, is if the alternative explanation is viable, for the gallium anomaly, that of energetic neutrinos  transforming to free electrons (e.g. $\nu_e+n \quad \rightarrow \quad e^{-}+p$) thus the population of neutrinos inside the gallium is reduced and this could be the reason for the about 20% deficiency observed in the production of germanium atoms from gallium interaction with neutrinos, ${ }^{71} \mathrm{Ga}+\nu_e \rightarrow e^{-}+{ }^{71} \mathrm{Ge}$.

In what sense is your proposed reaction an alternative? In the Ga → Ge → Ga reaction sequence, aka the "Alsace-Lorraine" technique, a neutron in Ga-71 reacts with a neutrino, converting the neutron to a proton and the neutrino to an electron.

The neutrino + neutron reaction you suggest is the same charged-current weak reaction that produces 71Ge in the target. The probability for this reaction, as well as other weak interactions, is very small and could not decrease the flux of neutrinos by 20% without other non-observed consequences for neutrino physics. This would be the case, even if you were proposing interactions with neutrons other than those contained within 71Ge.

What about the Neutrino electron swap (Wolfenstein matter effect) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikheyev%E2%80%93Smirnov%E2%80%93Wolfenstein_effect ? Could this effect be accounted fot this deficiency? What if the neutrino created during the swap is not an electron neutrino but a muon neutrino that does not create more electrons  $\nu_\mu+n \quad \rightarrow \quad \mu^{-}+p$  in the gallium target or of very low energy electron neutrino that does not interact with protons and therefore does not contribute to germanium production?
